# React JS: Why am I getting error at componentdidMount()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-props

The following is my parent component:

```
const movies = [896, 895]

    const cards = movies.map(movie =>{
        <FlipCard number = {'movie'} />
    })
```

In the child component I am trying to access the props.number, but I am getting an error. The code of child component:

```
state = {
        poster: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500',
    }

     componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + {this.props.number} + '?api_key=*******&language=en-US')
            .then(
                    res=>{
                        this.setState({poster: this.state.poster + res.data.poster_path})   
                        console.log(this.props);             
                        }
                )   
        }
```

In browser, I am getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYESw.png) [Unexpected keyword 'this' at this.props.number]

In VS Code, I am getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M854d.png) [ ':' expected at that axios line]

How can I resolve this issue?

**EDIT**:
I did remove the curly braces. Now componentdidMount() is not firing at all. Even the console.logs are not being shown. Why? Please help.!

Comment: that isn't valid javascript - remove the curlies

Comment: Try to remove `{}` from `{this.props.number}`

Comment: @Peter   I did it. No error is being shown. But componentDidMount() is not firing at all. Even the console.logs inside it are not being displayed. Why?

Comment: @DanielA.White please refer the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the code in the following way:
In your parent component:

```
const movies = [896, 895]

const cards = movies.map(movie => {
   <FlipCard number = 'movie' />
})
```

In your child component

```
state = {
  poster: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500',
}

componentDidMount() {
   axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.number}api_key=*******&language=en-US`
.then(res=>{
    this.setState({poster: this.state.poster + res.data.poster_path})   
    console.log(this.props);             
})}
```

Comment: I did what you said. The error no longer exsists. However, componentdidMount() is no longer firing. Even the console.logs are not being shown! Pls help.

Comment: I think your API call is not returning a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue and write better code using arrow functions and async await method

```
state = {
  poster: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500',
}

componentDidMount() {
  getPoster()
} 

const getPoster = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.number}api_key=*******&language=en-US`)
    this.setState({poster: this.state.poster + response.data.poster_path})   
    console.log(this.props);             
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```